# How resolve dependencies, when generate signned APK

Tags: android, gradle, build, dependencies, signed

When i start generate signed APK, this log is appear. i don't know what to do with this

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleRelease] in project C:\Users\Andrey\Desktop\AndroidStudioProjects\Learning\MyMovies2
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:{strictly 1.3.9}.
 Required by:
     project :app
  > Cannot find a version of 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305' that satisfies the version constraints: 
       Dependency path 'My Movies 2:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1'
       Constraint path 'My Movies 2:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:{strictly 1.3.9}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.3.9
       Dependency path 'My Movies 2:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-guava:2.0.0' --> 'com.google.guava:guava:23.6-android' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
> Could not resolve com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1.
 Required by:
     project :app > androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0
  > Cannot find a version of 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305' that satisfies the version constraints: 
       Dependency path 'My Movies 2:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1'
       Constraint path 'My Movies 2:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:{strictly 1.3.9}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.3.9
       Dependency path 'My Movies 2:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-guava:2.0.0' --> 'com.google.guava:guava:23.6-android' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
> Could not resolve com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9.
 Required by:
     project :app > com.google.guava:guava:23.6-android
  > Cannot find a version of 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305' that satisfies the version constraints: 
       Dependency path 'My Movies 2:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1'
       Constraint path 'My Movies 2:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:{strictly 1.3.9}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.3.9
       Dependency path 'My Movies 2:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-guava:2.0.0' --> 'com.google.guava:guava:23.6-android' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
 * BUILD FAILED in 735ms

Answer (score 0):

Fix it just add/edit this line to **build.gradle** in the **(module:app)** under dependencies
and rebulid the project, might solve this problem.

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
```

try and let me know Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for respond i just add this code to gradle module app:

```
androidTestImplementation ('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'){
        exclude group: "com.google.code.findbugs", module: "jsr305"
           }
```